# Python "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and i don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am making an OOP program and I got a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".
Here is the part of the code `File "main.py", line 56
    def __init __(self, side1, side2):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no space between `init` and `__`

So it should be `def __init__(self, side1, side2):`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice it.